# normalization of a table

Tags: sql, normalization

I have this table, i have to normalize up to 3nf

Assume the following:

- An Order can contain multiple products
- Everytime a customer places an Order, they get a new order number
- An Order belongs to one and only one customer

  Orders (OrderNum, OrderDate, (ProductId,ProductDesc),CustId,CustomerName,CustomerAddress)

So far i have done this

`1FN`

```
Orders (OrderNum, OrderDate, (ProductId,ProductDesc),(CustId,CustomerName,CustomerAddress, OrderNum))
```

`2FN`

```
Orders(OrderNum, OrderDate)
Orders_Product(OrderNum,  ProductId)
Product(ProductId, ProductDesc)
Customer_Orders(OrderNum, CustId)
Customer(CustId,CustomerName,CustomerAddress)
```

`3 NF`

The tables already fulfill  the 3NF

```
Orders(OrderNum, OrderDate)
Orders_Product(OrderNum,  ProductId)
Product(ProductId, ProductDesc)
Customer_Orders(OrderNum, CustId)
Customer(CustId,CustomerName,CustomerAddress)
```

Dependencies

```
OrderNum  OrderDate,ProductId,ProductDesc,CustId, CustomerName, CustomerAddress 
    ProductId  ProductDesc
    CustId   CustomerName, CustomerAddress
```

is it my 2NF and 3Nf correct?

Comment: I think only your 2NF is wrong. Read this: [Second Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)

Comment: I don't remember what 2NF is supposed to look like. However, in your 3NF model, I don't think that you need the Customer_Orders table. You should just have a CustId on your Orders table.

Comment: Why do you think his 2NF is wrong?

Comment: Because on the 2NF there are an acceptable level of data duplication. And I aggre with @OlivierDeMeulder you don't need the `Customer_Orders` unless two customers can have the same order. Which is not the case since you have this requirement: `An Order belongs to one and only one customer`

Comment: I think his 2NF is OK, base on Wiki definition. See my answer :)

Comment: You are right when there is no comparing with the 2NF and 3NF. When you have to present those differences, there is a tyne spot. See on that same wiki page the part of "Not all 2NF tables are free from update anomalies". But I agree that, aside the Customer_Orders table, his 2nf and 3nf can be considered right. :)

Comment: Your 1NF schema isn't 1NF, there's a duplicated OrderNum column and nested parentheses indicating repeating groups.  Your 2NF schema isn't just in 2NF, it's fully normalized.  2NF without further normalization would've looked like 1NF since everything already depends on the whole key.  Your 3NF is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the definition from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form): a table is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and **no non-prime attribute is dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key of the table**. Most of your tables only have 2 columns, so they satisfied this. For `Customer(CustId,CustomerName,CustomerAddress)`, the candidate key is `CustId`, and the other 2 columns completely depend on the whole candidate key, then it's OK.

For 3NF, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) said: **all the attributes in a table are determined only by the candidate keys of that table and not by any non-prime attributes**. As you see, your tables are all satisfied.

However, as you said:

> An Order belongs to one and only one customer

So, I don't think you need `Customer_Orders` number. You should remove it, and place `CustId` in `Orders` table. So, your `Orders` table will look like this: `Orders(OrderNum, OrderDate, CustId)`